# Class Must Implement the Global interface method: Iterable<SObject> start Database

Tags: apex, batch

Given the following code:

```
global class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    global MyBatch() {}

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<MyBatch Field__c> batch)
    {

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
}
```

What does this error Message mean?

> MyBatch: Class must implement the global interface method:
>   Iterable<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext) from
>   Database.Batchable<SObject>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you're missing a particular method; the interface is trying to enforce the implementation of this class.

So adding this method to the `MyBatch` class will resolve the issue:

```
    global Database.Querylocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
       return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

Comment: n.b. Unless you are doing managed packages, you can use `public` rather than `global` as access modifier throughout your batch class

Comment: @crop1645 That's good to know. Thank you!

Comment: yep - I learned it from @sfdcfox who knows everything

Comment: You can write a batch in a managed package that uses public rather than global too. Global is only needed to expose the class or method to code outside the package.